# How to convert RHEL rpm to CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm

My team receives software in a RHEL format from another team. RHEL requires licensing to use and deliver their media. Our team converts the operating system to CentOS which is based on RHEL but does not include licensing and support.

What I need to know is what parts are ok to be released without changes. We have several hundred RPMs that are packaged for RHEL; however, the libraries and files contained inside most of those RPMs are the same for RHEL and CentOS. The big ones that change are redhat-release, redhat-release-notes, yum-rhn-plugin, and redhat-logos. If we simply replaced these with the appropriate CentOS equivalents, can we legally deliver the rest of the packages as-is?

Comment: yum-rhn-plugin can be kept. This was originaly removed in CentOS as it was only used with RHN, but since existence of Spacewalk it actually has sense. There is no licensing issues with yum-rhn-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is a migration guide in the CentOs wiki https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide it has a section on **Migrate an existing system from RHEL6 or SL6 to CentOS 6**